# What is Rails’ scaffold functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I recently starting trying out ruby on rails and I am not sure what scaffolds are for in rails.

Say I run this command: 
rails generate scaffold idea name:string description:text picture:string

What exactly is it doing apart from creating new files in your project directory? Is it creating a table for the database?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is all in the docs and most tutorials. You can *see* what happens by looking in your project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Rails guide on [scaffolding](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding).

When you use the generate scaffold command, you're creating a migration (which will create a table when you run `rake db:migrate`), views, css, script files, initial tests, etc. Think of the literal meaning of the term "scaffold" as "a structure around which something is constructed" and scaffolding starts to make a lot of sense.

Comment: To be pedantic, it doesn't create the table, it creates the migration.

Comment: Pedantry isn't a vice when dealing with machines. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Direct from command line:

```
[root@mayureshmayur test_scaffold]# rails g scaffold
Running via Spring preloader in process 2715
Usage:
  rails generate scaffold NAME [field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]] [options]

Options:
      [--skip-namespace], [--no-skip-namespace]             # Skip namespace (affects only isolated applications)
      [--force-plural], [--no-force-plural]                 # Forces the use of the given model name
  -o, --orm=NAME                                            # ORM to be invoked
                                                            # Default: active_record
      [--model-name=MODEL_NAME]                             # ModelName to be used
      [--resource-route], [--no-resource-route]             # Indicates when to generate resource route
                                                            # Default: true
      [--api], [--no-api]                                   # Indicates when to generate api
  -y, [--stylesheets], [--no-stylesheets]                   # Generate Stylesheets
                                                            # Default: true
  -se, [--stylesheet-engine=STYLESHEET_ENGINE]              # Engine for Stylesheets
                                                            # Default: scss
      [--assets], [--no-assets]                             # Indicates when to generate assets
                                                            # Default: true
  -ss, [--scaffold-stylesheet], [--no-scaffold-stylesheet]  # Indicates when to generate scaffold stylesheet
                                                            # Default: true
  -c, --scaffold-controller=NAME                            # Scaffold controller to be invoked
                                                            # Default: scaffold_controller

ActiveRecord options:
      [--migration], [--no-migration]        # Indicates when to generate migration
                                             # Default: true
      [--timestamps], [--no-timestamps]      # Indicates when to generate timestamps
                                             # Default: true
      [--parent=PARENT]                      # The parent class for the generated model
      [--indexes], [--no-indexes]            # Add indexes for references and belongs_to columns
                                             # Default: true
      [--primary-key-type=PRIMARY_KEY_TYPE]  # The type for primary key
  -t, [--test-framework=NAME]                # Test framework to be invoked
                                             # Default: test_unit

TestUnit options:
      [--fixture], [--no-fixture]    # Indicates when to generate fixture
                                     # Default: true
  -r, [--fixture-replacement=NAME]   # Fixture replacement to be invoked
      [--system-tests=SYSTEM_TESTS]  # Skip system test files
                                     # Default: test_unit

ScaffoldController options:
      [--helper], [--no-helper]      # Indicates when to generate helper
                                     # Default: true
  -e, [--template-engine=NAME]       # Template engine to be invoked
                                     # Default: erb
      [--jbuilder], [--no-jbuilder]  # Indicates when to generate jbuilder
                                     # Default: true

Asset options:
  -j, [--javascripts], [--no-javascripts]       # Generate JavaScripts
                                                # Default: true
  -je, [--javascript-engine=JAVASCRIPT_ENGINE]  # Engine for JavaScripts
                                                # Default: coffee

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Description:
    Scaffolds an entire resource, from model and migration to controller and
    views, along with a full test suite. The resource is ready to use as a
    starting point for your RESTful, resource-oriented application.

    Pass the name of the model (in singular form), either CamelCased or
    under_scored, as the first argument, and an optional list of attribute
    pairs.

    Attributes are field arguments specifying the model's attributes. You can
    optionally pass the type and an index to each field. For instance:
    'title body:text tracking_id:integer:uniq' will generate a title field of
    string type, a body with text type and a tracking_id as an integer with an
    unique index. "index" could also be given instead of "uniq" if one desires
    a non unique index.

    As a special case, specifying 'password:digest' will generate a
    password_digest field of string type, and configure your generated model,
    controller, views, and test suite for use with Active Model
    has_secure_password (assuming they are using Rails defaults).

    Timestamps are added by default, so you don't have to specify them by hand
    as 'created_at:datetime updated_at:datetime'.

    You don't have to think up every attribute up front, but it helps to
    sketch out a few so you can start working with the resource immediately.

    For example, 'scaffold post title body:text published:boolean' gives
    you a model with those three attributes, a controller that handles
    the create/show/update/destroy, forms to create and edit your posts, and
    an index that lists them all, as well as a resources :posts declaration
    in config/routes.rb.

    If you want to remove all the generated files, run
    'rails destroy scaffold ModelName'.

Examples:
    `rails generate scaffold post`
    `rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text published:boolean`
    `rails generate scaffold purchase amount:decimal tracking_id:integer:uniq`
    `rails generate scaffold user email:uniq password:digest`
```